# Get model property that is currently been written in a custom razor base page

Tags: c#, razor

I have a custom Razor base page. Inheriting from

```
WebViewPage<TModel>
```

I have overriden this method:

```
 public override Write(object value)
```

But in this method I want to know which property is currently been written out.

Right now I dynamically search my model for a property with this specific value, but that doesn't seem optimal.
I have looked at all the 'base.???' properties, but can't find anything that could possibly give me access to the property that is currently been written out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.

Comment: I thought so already. Thanks for confirming.